# ImportError : cannot import name "XGBClassifier"

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, xgboost

I am under anaconda notebook.

I have recently installed xgboost but I cannot access XGBClassifier :

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
```

When I import only xgboost and write xgboost it prints that the module is here ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that I did not install xgboost for anaconda, so writing :

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost=0.6a2
```

solved my problem, thank you

Comment: The following packages are not available from current channels:- xgboost=0.6a2 is what giving me in anaconda prompt

Comment: How to install XGBClassifier using pip?

Answer (score 26):

Mine works after **renaming** the py file I was working on.
I my case, from 'xgboost' to something else.

P.S. Restarting anaconda/spyder didn't work for me

Comment: A file named xgboost.py overwrites the module you're trying to load. You'll need to make sure there are no files of that name in your working directory.

Answer (score 1):

use this instead : -

```
import xgboost as xgb
xgb_regressor = xgb.XGBRegressor()
```

This worked for me.......

Answer (score 0):

Install xgboost in anaconda,
conda install conda-forge::xgboost

Answer (score 0):

Install xgboost on anaconda3, `pip install xgboost`

After that when importing the library use

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor
```

Works perfectly